# linq query with db2 xml column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, collections, db2

In my db2 database i have below columns

```
IdInstanceTag int,
APPROVED_TIME timestamp,
ModifiedTime date,
DATE_TO date,
DEFINITION XML,
ID int,
CreatedBy varchar(100),
ModifiedBy varchar(100)
```

In the above columns having the data, the xml column data look like below.

```
<Template xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xsi:type="GlobalTemplateDefinition" Name="TrinadhDemo" AgentLevel="Location" APSRatioPercent="50" xmlns="urn:wu-compliance-iwatch:gfo">
<Sections>
<Section ID="1" Name="S1" WeightOrPoints="0">
<Questions>
<CoreQuestion xsi:type="FreeTextQuestion" ID="1" Text="Q1 Free Text" IsOptional="false">
<MaximumQAPoints xsi:nil="true"/>
</CoreQuestion>
<CoreQuestion xsi:type="CalendarQuestion" ID="2" Text="Q2 Calendar control" IsOptional="false">
<MaximumQAPoints xsi:nil="true"/>
</CoreQuestion>
<CoreQuestion xsi:type="FixedListQuestion" ID="3" Text="Q3 Free List" IsOptional="false" MultiSelectAvailable="false">
<MaximumQAPoints xsi:nil="true"/>
<Rule ParentQuestionID="2" EnableValue="IN" RuleSpecification="Equal"/>
<Options><string>IN</string><string>US</string></Options>
</CoreQuestion>
<CoreQuestion xsi:type="YesNoQuestion" ID="4" Text="erfcewrf" IsOptional="false" Score="0" IsNAAvailable="false" SuppressFindingTextBox="false">
<MaximumQAPoints xsi:nil="true"/>
<ScoreInSectionID xsi:nil="true"/>
<FindingDescription>wdqcfvewr</FindingDescription>
<Actions><string>Action 1</string><string>Action 2</string><string>Action 3</string></Actions>
</CoreQuestion>
</Questions>
</Section>
</Sections>
</Template>
```

My requirement is how to retrive the columns and " AgentLevel" attribute value from Definition column. i written the below query

```
ctx => from oInterviewTemplate in ctx.InterviewTemplate
                        join oCreatedUser in ctx.Users on oInterviewTemplate.CreatedUserId equals oCreatedUser.UserId
                            into oCreatedUserJoin
                        from oCreatedUserResult in oCreatedUserJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join oModifedUser in ctx.Users on oInterviewTemplate.ModifiedByUserId equals oModifedUser.UserId
                            into oModifedUserJoin
                        from oModifedUserResult in oModifedUserJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where ((interviewTemplateTypeId==null && oInterviewTemplate.ParentId==null) 
                        || (interviewTemplateTypeId!=null && oInterviewTemplate.ParentId!=null))
                        orderby oInterviewTemplate.Id ascending
                        select new InterviewTemplateLookup
                        {
                            InterviewTypeID = oInterviewTemplate.Id,
                            Id = oInterviewTemplate.Id,
                            InterviewTypeDescription = oInterviewTemplate.Name,
                            Name = oInterviewTemplate.Name,
                            IsApproved = oInterviewTemplate.ApprovedTime == null ? "No" : "Yes",
                            CreatedBy = oCreatedUserResult.FirstName + " " + oCreatedUserResult.LastName,
                            ModifiedBy = oModifedUserResult.FirstName + " " + oModifedUserResult.LastName,
                            CreatedTime = oInterviewTemplate.CreatedTime,
                            Status = oInterviewTemplate.IsDeleted == 0 ? "Active" : "Inactive",
                            ModifiedTime = oInterviewTemplate.ModifiedTime,
                            IdInstanceTag=oInterviewTemplate.IdInstanceTag,
                        });
```

i am retriening all the above columns from the table but i can't able to read that xml column attribute value "AgentLevel", Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't think `DEFINITION` or `AgentLevel` is referenced in your query at all.

Comment: actually i don't know how to retrieve the agent level attribute value by using  that query...

Comment: `IdInstanceTag` - I like this name, is it an ID?, an Instance?, a Tag?  No one knows.